# Applying CSS color to text input but still be able to override it with a class

Tags: css, css-specificity

I'm trying to figure out how to specify a default style for text inputs that can still be overridden.     In this case, I would like the second input to have a red background, however it has the same background as the first input.

```css
input[type=text] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background: #99C;
}

.error {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<input type=text value=XYZZY><br>
<input type=checkbox> XYZZY<br>
<input type=text class=error value=XYZZY><br>
<div class=error>XYZZY</div>
```

If I remove the `[type=text]` from the `input` rule it fixes the problem for the second text area, but it makes the style apply to the checkbox as well (which I don't want.)

I can change the `.error` rule to `.error, input.error` but I don't want to have to do that for every class I might possibly want to apply to a text input.

Is there some way to make the `[type=text]` rule less specific while still only applying to text inputs so that it doesn't get applied in preference to straight class rules?

Comment: This is an acceptable situation in which to use `!important`.

Comment: That has it's own problems.  Then you can't override the `.error` styling further without using `!important` again.

Comment: Why not just exclusively utilize classes?

Comment: Not all the text inputs on my site currently have a class, and there are a lot of them on various pages.

Comment: Assuming there's a local copy or capable IDE, I'd deploy a multi-file complex regex to find/replace anything without a class, but that might just be personal preference.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Well sure. At some point, you won't be able to overwrite something. That just how specificity works. What situation would you have where you need to hide an error highlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that I can artificially increase the specificity of a rule by duplicating the class.   Instead of `.error` I can write `.error.error`.   This appears to allow the rule to be more specific than the `[type=text]` rule while still allowing it to be overridden in a sane manner:

```css
input[type=text] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background: #99C;
}

.error.error {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.container .error {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<input type=text value=XYZZY><br>
<input type=checkbox> XYZZY<br>
<input type=text class=error value=XYZZY><br>
<div class=error>XYZZY</div>
<div class=container><div class=error>XYZZY</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a wrapper for these so you can use the `wrapper id` and `classname` to get this div and it will be a stronger css selector. 
Use this [website](https://specificity.keegan.st/) to calculate which selector is stronger .

Every `id` has 100 points , `class` has 10 points and `tag` has 1 point.
So if you use `id` + `class` it will be more stronger and the style should apply

Check this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39039486/why-isnt-my-stylesheet-overwritting-bootstraps/39039655#39039655) question and answer to better understand.

Comment: I didn't know about the point system.   I wasn't expecting a rule based on attributes to increase the specificity at all.    Certainly it seems to me like it should be weighted far less than a class.  I wish there were a way to decrease the specificity of a rule artificially.

Comment: This is cool that's why we use id because it's more stronger than everything except inline style that has 1000 points and !important. But you can increase the specificity by targeting two parents up for example. You see like in the other post that i posted the bootstrap sometimes uses this to make their specificity stronger and we sometimes can't replace the css even if it's below the bootstrap css file.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller if that worked for you please choose as correct :)